# How to create object array in ext js4 and set values to it?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am working in extjs4 MVC. Where i am getting stuck at a point**.Which is how to define object array in extjs4 and set values to it as well as retrieve values from that object.**I am tried but not yet solved.
Suppose I have Qusetion paper.Which displays some question with there options.I have got qustion with proper selected option.But I am not succeed to store it in proper models instance.I know how to store single record to particular model instance.But I dont know how to store repetative values to a particular model object.How I solve this probelm.

1) here is my some contrller file code

```
temp:function()
    {
        var obj = Ext.create('Demo.model.Poll');
        for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
                var inputs = document.getElementsByName(i); 
                var radio = "";  
                for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
                    if (inputs[j].checked) {
                        name = inputs[j].name;
                        value  = inputs[j].value;
                        //console.log("questionId="+name +" value="+ value);
                        check.set('poll',name);
                        check.set('option',value);
                    }// End of if statment
                }// End of inner for loop
          }//End of outer for loop

        //Here I am going to display values inside object  
        console.log("----------------------------------");
          for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
          {
              console.log(i);
              console.log(check.get('poll'));
              console.log(check.get('option'));
          }
    //Is it possible to save object array to server side in single save method
    //  obj.save();

}// End of temp function
```

2) And after running this code i got last set value to model.In firebug i got this result.
for exampl.

```
3 
England 

3 
England 

3 
England


3 
England
```

please give me some suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my question and here is the answer.

```
//code for getting question name and value from view and send to server side in a asingle request
check:function()
{
    //creating objects in javascript
        var storeObject=this.getStore('qb.QbquestionoptionStore');
    for(var i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
            var inputs = document.getElementsByName(i); 
            var radio = "";  
            for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
                if (inputs[j].checked) {
                    name = inputs[j].name;
                    value  = inputs[j].value;
                    console.log("questionId="+name +" value="+ value);
                        var check = Ext.create('Balaee.model.qb.QbquestionoptionModel');
                        check.set('questionId',name);
                        check.set('option',value);

                    storeObject.add(check);
                  //console.log("User Infooooooooo: option="+check.get('option')+"questionId="+check.get('questionId'));
                }// End of if statment
            }// End of inner for loop
      }//End of outer for loop
    // code to display data in store object 
      for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
      {
          var record=storeObject.getAt(i);
          console.log("record no="+i);
          console.log("Qusetion Id="+record.get('questionId'));
          console.log("Option="+record.get('option'));
          console.log();
      }
      storeObject.sync();
}// End of check function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,
var myObj = [];

```
for(.....)
{
   myObj.push(
      {
        'poll' : name, 
        'option' : value
      });
}
```

to access,

```
var i;
for(i=0; i<myObj.length; i++)
{
   console.log(myObj[i].poll);
   console.log(myObj[i].option);
}
```